# Flutter Get Request with Bearer Token (JWT) - Django Backend

Tags: flutter, dart, django-rest-framework, get, jwt

I have the Api key that I get from login. How do I use that key to make http.get request to the server?

This is my key:

```
"access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTU5MTc3NDg4LCJqdGkiOiIxZGU5MzlkNTNiYWQ0NDM4OWZjOGQ5MDJmYmRkMzYzMyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.vQFnfQSeTgxeOav--H4a5nf2Rs0xMWyDRewp9kkZXks"
```

Exercise Class:

```
class Exercise {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Exercise(this.id, this.name);

  Exercise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> j)
  : id = j['id'],
    name = j['name'];
}
```

Get Request without token (Won't work, and I need a solution):

```
Future<List<Exercise>> _getExercises() async {
http.Response data = await http.get(
  'url:8000/api/database/exercises/');
List jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
List<Exercise> allExercises = jsonData.map<Exercise>((j) => Exercise.fromJson(j)).toList();
return allExercises;
}
```

Comment: have you fixed the issue?